# Compiler error when using function in lazy stored property

Tags: swift, lazy-evaluation, swift2

I am getting an error that says "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to argument type 'Test'" when trying to return a value from a function in lazy stored property. I am not able to spot any issue in the lazy var's closure.

```
import UIKit

public struct Value {}

public class Test {

    var id: String = ""

    public func getValueById(id: String) -> Value {
        return Value()
    }

    public lazy var value: Value = {
        // Compiler error: Cannot convert value of 'String' to expected argument type 'Test'
        return getValueById(self.id)
    }() 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is confused about `getValueById` and the error message is meaningless - if not misleading.

What you need is to add `self` in front of `getValueById(self.id)` inside the closure:

```
public struct Value {}

public class Test {

    var id: String = ""

    public func getValueById(id: String) -> Value {
        return Value()
    }

    public lazy var value: Value = {
        return self.getValueById(self.id)
    }() 
}
```

Comment: That's correct.Here's the quote from the ARC chapter, section Resolving Strong Reference Cycles for Closures (The Swift Programming Language) - _Swift requires you to write self.someProperty or self.someMethod() (rather than just someProperty or someMethod()) whenever you refer to a member of self within a closure. This helps you remember that it’s possible to capture self by accident._